# HDRI environment texture doesn't load

Tags: shaders

For some reason on the current computer/blender setup that I am using the HDRI texutres from HDRheaven isn't working. I've downloaded couple of them but can't make them work. Is some checkmark missing that I'm not aware of?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in look *'dev mode'*. Change it to '*rendered*'.

[image]

Or activate *'Scene world'* here:

[image]